# Only one item from jdbc mysql data shows up in my html dropdown split up as characters - Appscript. Why?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, google-apps-script, jdbc

I am setting up an HTML dropdown displaying items from our Google Cloud SQL data. However, there is something wrong with  my code and can't figure it out.

Here is my code:

**CODE.GS**

```
function doGet(e){
 var listfiltered = subjectfromDB(subjectdb)

  var tmp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("page");
  tmp.listfiltered = listfiltered;

   return tmp.evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME).setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL).addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1');

}


function subjectfromDB(){

  var connectionName = 'xxxxxx';
  var user = 'xxxxx';
  var userPwd = 'xxxxx';
  var db = 'xxxxxx';
  var dbUrl = 'jdbc:google:mysql://' + connectionName + '/' + db;
  var conn = Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection(dbUrl, user, userPwd);

  var start = new Date();
  var stmt = conn.createStatement();
  stmt.setMaxRows(1000);
  var results = stmt.executeQuery('SELECT SubjectName FROM Subject WHERE SubjectArchived != true');
  var numCols = results.getMetaData().getColumnCount();

  while (results.next()) {
    var rowString = '';
    for (var col = 0; col < numCols; col++) {
      rowString += results.getString(col + 1) + '\t';
    }
    Logger.log(rowString);
  }

  results.close();
  stmt.close();

  return rowString;

}
```

**HTML**

```
<select id="case1" name="case" class="validate browser-default" required>
            <option value="" disabled selected>Select Case</option>

           <? for (var i=0;i<listfiltered.length;i++){ ?>
           <option><?= listfiltered[i]; ?></option>

           <? } ?>

          </select>
          </div>
```

It only returns 1 item on the dropdown list. By the way, I used google apps script here.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you very much!

[image: OUTPUT]

Comment: See [ask]. Title should summarize the problem and should not be the summary of the entire project. A better title would be "Only one item from jdbc mysql data shows up in my html dropdown split up as characters. Why?"

Comment: @TheMaster this is noted sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem**

Watch your types closely - `subjectfromDB()` returns a `String`, which you then pass to the template via `listfiltered` property. Once the template evaluates, your loop starts to iterate over `listfiltered`, which means that it iterates over *each character* in the `String`.

**Solution**

```
var options = [];

while (results.next()) {
  var rowString = '';
  for (var col = 0; col < numCols; col++) {
    rowString += results.getString(col + 1) + '\t';
  }
  options.push(rowString));
}

results.close();
stmt.close();

return options;
```

**Notes**

1. In your code sample, the `subjectfromDB` function is called with `subjectdb` as its first argument, but it is declared to accept no parameters - please, check if this is intentional.

Comment: Hi @RJVillamer, happy to help :)